# Having trouble to switch in Ahci

Tags: ssd, bios, ahci

I can't find any keyword saying "ahci" on my bios, and there were no solution on the net ( I didn't find any :( ). My system is so old, so i bought a ssd to boost some performance and therefore in search to turn on ahci mode.

Motherboard: GA-EG41MFT-US2H (rev. 1.0);
Ram: 4+2 GB 1333Mhz;
Processor: core 2 duo e7500.

Answer (score 1):

[The Gigabyte's downloads page for the GA-EG41MFT-US2H (rev. 1.0) offers the user's manual in several languages.](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-EG41MFT-US2H-rev-10/support#support-manual)

In the English version, p. 45, it shows the BIOS settings for the drives. It supports IDE only, not AHCI.

Setting it to "AUTO" should correctly detect any SATA drive. HDD or SSD doesn't matter. However, expect the performance to be way below the drive's specifications because the motherboard uses [SATA II standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_2.0_(3_Gbit/s,_300_MB/s,_Serial_ATA-300)). Any SATA SSD, as well as any SATA HDD from 2010 or newer, expect SATA III.

Comment: Most SSDs require AHCI support, of course we are talking about SATA HDDS, so those might not require it.

Comment: @Ramhound Most SATA SSDs can work with "IDE" but they'll be slow as to really not justify the investment for such old motherboards. It's like throwing money to a pit. Even the slight improvement over a good 7200rpm HDD will be imperceptible due to the bottleneck other components will create.